# Pulumi Azure ARM template deployment error

Tags: azure, pulumi

Got error 'resourceGroupName' is not defined for Azure ARM template deployment

```
File "./__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
        resourceGroupName: resource_group.name,
    NameError: name 'resourceGroupName' is not defined
```

relevant part of code here, not sure where to look for TemplateDeployment docs , can't see them in API reference

```
armDeployment = azure.core.TemplateDeployment("test-dep", {
    resourceGroupName: resource_group.name,
    templateBody: JSON.stringify(content),
    parameters: {
        "storageAccountType": "Standard_GRS",
    },
    deploymentMode: "Incremental",
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/adopting/from_azure/) the correct property name for the resource group is: `resource_group_name` and also `template_body` not `templateBody`.
So it should work if you change it like this:

```
armDeployment = azure.core.TemplateDeployment("test-dep", {
     resource_group_name: resource_group.name,
     template_body: JSON.stringify(content),
     parameters: {
        "storageAccountType": "Standard_GRS",
     },
     deployment_mode: "Incremental",
})
```